# VB code functions Randomize() and like more in c#

Tags: c#, vb.net, vb.net-to-c#

Let me know how to write the this three function in c#:
Randomize, Int ,Ran()

**Randomize();**

```
    //  This is my VB Code
    for (  ; (KeyOK(sKey) == false); )
    {
        for ( ; (PartOK(sPart2) == false);  )
        {
            sPart2 = "";
            for (lCount = 1; (lCount <= PART_LENGTH); lCount++) {
                sPart2 = (sPart2 +  Int((10 *  Rnd())).ToString());
            }
        }
```

Comment: That does not look like VB...

Comment: Sorry Hans Passant..i will not repet this type of trival questions once again.My problem is am to this VB.net.That's why i asked help.

Answer (score 0):

Use the class `Random` to get a random number.

```
 Random rnd = new Random();
```

Then use one of the overloaded method calls of the `Next()` method to get a random number.

Answer (score 0):

That's not VB code, that's some strange mix...

First create a `Random` object (outside the loop):

```
Random rnd = new Random();
```

Use the `Next` method to get a random number from it:

```
sPart2 += rnd.Next(0, 10).ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, note that most VB built-in functions and constants can be found in the [`Microsoft.VisualBasic`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c157t28f%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) namespace (including `MsgBox`, which looks kinda strange in C# but I find it practical sometimes), which is accessible by C# .

Now, `Random` has been explained already. `Int` can be translated in different ways. Mostly with a conversion to `int`, but for special behaviour look at `Math.Round`, `Math.Floor` and `Math.Ceiling`.